# Where can I get man pages with examples

Tags: unix

Where can I get man pages with examples. I can improve my coding knowledge.

Comment: You have to tell us at least in which topics you are interested in

Comment: ok,I am interested in manpages.manpage should have example

Answer (score 2):

There is no better place than /usr/share/man/man3.  There are tons and tons of examples there (section 3 is the API section, which I think is what you want; your description wasn't really clear).

Comment: http://linux.die.net/man is useful for browsing, so to speak.

Comment: Example: If you're looking for information on the printf function type: man 3 printf

Comment: @das_weezul: I think you should explain where wasim needs to type that.

Comment: ok,I want shmget system call description and example

Comment: @wasim: Then type (under linux): man 3 shmget

Comment: ok.I know but it give only description and there is no related example

Answer (score 2):

Nothing beats a good book. Michael Kerrisk, the Linux manpages maintainer, has published a book titled "The Linux Programming Interface". There are also lots of older books on Unix programming, the most famous of them is probably "Advanced Programming in the Unix Environment", by the late W. Richard Stevens.